# Upload Work Items using Bulk Import in non 'New' State in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, upload, tfs-workitem

We have a handful of User Stories and associated Tasks which we want to upload to Azure DevOps (ADO). For upload we are using the Bulk Work Item Import feature of ADO.

The issue is that ADO is allowing upload of these work items only in 'New' status, but we already have these User Stories and Tasks in progress or in closed status.

[image: ADO Upload Error]

How to upload Work Items in non 'New' states, like 'Closed' or 'Active'?

I don't want to first upload them all in New State and then Update them using the sheet as it will be too much of a work given we have lot of data.

Thanks,
Shubham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All work items you import are created in a new state. This rule means that you can't specify field values that don't meet the field rules for the `new state`.

Please refer to doc:[Import or update work items in bulk by using CSV file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops)

I’m afraid that you can’t import works items in `closed`or `Active` state.
You could submit a feature request via :[feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?space=21)

However, there is a flexible solution to solve your problem:

1  upload  your work items in `New`  state without manually to change the state to `Closed` or `Active`.(file:csv1)

2  export work items to CSV  uploaded in step 1 and you can create Queries(file:csv2)

3 make sure  that the work items are in same order in both files:csv1 and csv2

4 batch copy the state of all work items in csv1 to the column `State` in csv2 and update the state  and save cvs2

5 update existing work items